# Can I see in my profile how many votes I have spent on questions and how many on answers?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page

In my profile, I can see how many votes I've casted.

Is it possible to distinguish between question votes and answer votes?

Example:

> You've spent 20,456 votes. 2,122 were on questions, 18,334 were on answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll down to the bottom of the [summary tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107625/uwe-keim) in your profile and you should see this.

[image: Questions and Answers]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.